# Error adding data to Geodjango database: parse error... within geometry

Tags: sql, geodjango

I'm trying to insert some values into a Geodjango database, but getting errors. This is the table:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    placeid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    structidx = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    oscode = models.PointField(null=True, blank=True)
    waste86 = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

And this is the code I'm using to insert data:

```
INSERT INTO domes_place (placeid, structidx, oscode, holding)
  VALUES ('10', '1', '1', 'POINT(632000,141000)', 'N');
```

And this is the error:

```
HINT:  "POINT(632000," <-- parse error at position 13 within geometry
```

Please could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at the documentation on the Geodjango website, it looks like you don't need the `,` between the numbers, so give this a try:

```
INSERT INTO domes_place (placeid, structidx, oscode, holding)
  VALUES ('10', '1', '1', 'POINT(632000 141000)', 'N');
```

Looks like the missing `,` is a WKT(Well-Known Text) convention, never noticed it before.

Answer (score 1):

No comma: `'POINT(632000 141000)'`

See [WKT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) on Wikipedia for a quick reference to Well-Known Text.